# Broadcast receiver Or Services

Tags: java, android, services

I am creating an "Alarm Clock" app in Android. I learned that we can implement `OnReciever()` method and write those things which we want the alarm to do after an intent is fired.

But I have now come across the "Services" of android which is (might) be useful in the app.

Which one should I prefer, keeping in mind the simplicity of using either of them.

Comment: The choice of one approach other another often requires consideration of the entire structure of the application.  Can you give us any more details about the code (not the code itself... but things like how big is it, what patterns are you currently using?)

Answer (score 1):

Using a service is a bad idea. The system can kill at any time for example to free memory. You can make it a foreground service to get around this but that requires a persistent notification in the notification bar.

Instead take a look at the [AlarmClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) class. You have to create `BroadcastReceivers` to handle `ACTION_SET_ALARM` and `ACTION_SET_TIMER` `Intents`.